# Streamwriter will not save to FileName entered by User with Default var.FileName initiated - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, io, filenames, streamwriter

I am new here, and relatively new to VB.NET.  I have a specific problem with getting my StreamWriter to work properly.  One of the requirements of my project is to give the file a default name when the user clicks the Save button, which I have done by setting mysave.Filename = "MyLog.log".  I call a new instance of my streamwriter trying to save to the filename specified by the user (mySave.Filename again), but every time, it saves to the default MyLog.log file.   I have pasted my code below.

If someone could tell me how I can make sure the data is being saved to the value entered by the user for File name, that would be greatly beneficial.  Also, I apologize for the code format, its not perfectly readable, but I'm trying to learn how to use the 4 space indents to my advantage!!

Thanks!

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
Dim Initial As String = "C:\Users\Brian Frick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HW5_Frick_Creator\HW5_Frick_Creator\bin\Debug" 'give variable for full path without log file
Dim Fullpath As String = "C:\Users\Brian Frick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HW5_Frick_Creator\HW5_Frick_Creator\bin\Debug\MyLog.log" 'give one path for full path
Dim filewriter As New StreamWriter(Fullpath, True)

Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Application.Exit() ' quit application
    filewriter.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim mySave As New SaveFileDialog
    mySave.Filter = "LOG File (*.log)|*.log" 'set filter to .log
    mySave.DefaultExt = "log" 'set default extension
    mySave.InitialDirectory = Initial 'set default directory
    mySave.FileName = "MyLog.log"
    mySave.OverwritePrompt = True ' make sure to ask user if they want to over write
    If mySave.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim filewriter As New StreamWriter(mySave.FileName, True)

        filewriter.Close()

        'filewriter = New StreamWriter(mySave.FileName, True)
        'filewriter.Close() 'close filewriter to allow access to write directory
        'Dim Stream As New StreamWriter(mySave.FileName, True) 'save file to path chosen by user in SaveDialog
        'Stream.Close() ' Close stream to allow access to directory
        ' filewriter.Close()
    Else
        'dialog cancelled - no action
    End If
    filewriter.Close()
    filewriter = New StreamWriter(Fullpath, True) 're initiate filewriter to be used in successive iterations through the program without error
End Sub

Private Sub SavingsDepositBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SavingsDepositBtn.Click
    'write to file for SavDep
    filewriter.WriteLine("SavDep")
    filewriter.WriteLine(AccountBox.Text)
    filewriter.WriteLine(AmountBox.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub SavingsWithdrawBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SavingsWithdrawBtn.Click
    'write to file for SavWith
    filewriter.WriteLine("SavWith")
    filewriter.WriteLine(AccountBox.Text)
    filewriter.WriteLine(AmountBox.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub CheckDepsotBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckDepsotBtn.Click
    'write to file for CheckDep
    filewriter.WriteLine("CheckDep")
    filewriter.WriteLine(AccountBox.Text)
    filewriter.WriteLine(AmountBox.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub CheckWithdrawBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckWithdrawBtn.Click
    'write to file for CheckWith
    filewriter.WriteLine("CheckWith")
    filewriter.WriteLine(AccountBox.Text)
    filewriter.WriteLine(AmountBox.Text)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Oh, also sorry for including some of my commented out code.  I guess I should have left that out!

Answer (score 0):

the general way you are using the filewriter won't work, and there are some other serious issues like that there are two 'FileWriter' variables with overlapping scope.

for your save routine, you can't just re-instantiate your filewriter to point it to a different path. that will destroy all the data that had been in the underlying stream, so you are just saving nothing.

try caching the data in memory while the program is running, and don't create the stream until you are ready to write all the data to it, and it to a file, all in one go. your current approach makes it very hard to prevent leaking handles to the log files, so if the app crashes the user will have to reboot to release the write lock before they can run it again. look into the 'using' construct and 'Try... Finally'

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll try to catch the data in a string, and then write it using streamwriter.

Comment: Frank - Thanks again.  I forgot to come back and let you know how it worked out - I ended up not needing to cache anything in memory, as I really only needed 1 streamwriter, and it needed to be called multiple times throughout a single run of the program.  I thought I needed to use 'using' to make it work properly, but as long as I keep the streamwriter open for the entirety of the run, and close it at the end, all is working fine.  I have submitted this assignment and believe I will be getting an A on it.  Again, I appreciate your help -- even if I didn't use very much of it!  Thanks

Comment: anytime. just remember, you don;t want to use files in that manner in real-world scenarios, but glad its working for you.